# Обособление вводных конструкций 3

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Может ли кто-либо подсказать, считается ли конструкция в начале предложения вводной?.. Ведь здесь **по итогам** в значении **согласно**... И к тому же, предложение содержит указание на источник сообщения... Нужна ли запятая после слова *анкеты* и какое условие здесь имеет решающее значение?..

По итогам нашей анкеты журнал прочитывается на 50–70% от полного объема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**По итогам нашей анкеты, журнал прочитывается на 50–70% от полного объема.**

Оборот обособляется.

Во-первых, он **походит под тематику вводных слов** (указание на источник).

Кроме того, обособить оборот необходимо для того, чтобы **исключить некорректное управление**: журнал не может прочитываться по итогам.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ.